# Imported module default.register is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to port a Node/React system over to ES6 although I'm encountering an error when compiling.

```
GameSettingsStore.js:91 Uncaught TypeError: _dispatcher_AppDispatcher__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.register is not a function at Module../src/client/stores/GameSettingsStore.js
```

This line that appears to be throwing an error comes from this specific line/function:

```
import AppDispatcher from '../dispatcher/AppDispatcher';

AppDispatcher.register((payload) => {
  const { action } = payload;

  switch (action.actionType) {
    case Constants.ActionTypes.SET_CONTROLS_SIZE:
      GameSettingsStore._setControlsSize(action.controlsSize);
      GameSettingsStore.emitChange();
      break;

    case Constants.ActionTypes.SET_GRAPH_MODE:
      GameSettingsStore._setGraphMode(action.graphMode);
      GameSettingsStore.emitChange();
      break;

    case Constants.ActionTypes.TOGGLE_HOYTKEYS_STATE:
      GameSettingsStore._toggleHotkeysState();
      GameSettingsStore.emitChange();
      break;

    case Constants.ActionTypes.IGNORE_USER:
      GameSettingsStore._ignoreUser(action.username);
      GameSettingsStore.emitChange();
      break;

    case Constants.ActionTypes.APPROVE_USER:
      GameSettingsStore._approveUser(action.username);
      GameSettingsStore.emitChange();
      break;

    default:
      GameSettingsStore.emitChange();
      break;

  }
  return true;
});
```

And then the dispatcher system I'm using is the old Facebook one:

```
import invariant from 'invariant';

export default function () {

  let _lastID = 1;
  const _prefix = 'ID_';

  function Dispatcher() {
    this.$Dispatcher_callbacks = {};
    this.$Dispatcher_isPending = {};
    this.$Dispatcher_isHandled = {};
    this.$Dispatcher_isDispatching = false;
    this.$Dispatcher_pendingPayload = null;
  }

  Dispatcher.prototype.register = function (callback) {
    const id = _prefix + _lastID++;
    this.$Dispatcher_callbacks[id] = callback;
    return id;
  };

  Dispatcher.prototype.unregister = function (id) {
    invariant(
      this.$Dispatcher_callbacks[id],
      'Dispatcher.unregister(...): `%s` does not map to a registered callback.',
      id
    );
    delete this.$Dispatcher_callbacks[id];
  };

  Dispatcher.prototype.waitFor = function (ids) {
    invariant(
      this.$Dispatcher_isDispatching,
      'Dispatcher.waitFor(...): Must be invoked while dispatching.'
    );
    for (let ii = 0; ii < ids.length; ii++) {
      const id = ids[ii];
      if (this.$Dispatcher_isPending[id]) {
        invariant(
          this.$Dispatcher_isHandled[id],
          'Dispatcher.waitFor(...): Circular dependency detected while '
                    + 'waiting for `%s`.',
          id
        );
        continue;
      }
      invariant(
        this.$Dispatcher_callbacks[id],
        'Dispatcher.waitFor(...): `%s` does not map to a registered callback.',
        id
      );
      this.$Dispatcher_invokeCallback(id);
    }
  };

  Dispatcher.prototype.dispatch = function (payload) {
    invariant(
      !this.$Dispatcher_isDispatching,
      'Dispatch.dispatch(...): Cannot dispatch in the middle of a dispatch.'
    );
    this.$Dispatcher_startDispatching(payload);
    try {
      for (const id in this.$Dispatcher_callbacks) {
        if (this.$Dispatcher_isPending[id]) {
          continue;
        }
        this.$Dispatcher_invokeCallback(id);
      }
    } finally {
      this.$Dispatcher_stopDispatching();
    }
  };

  Dispatcher.prototype.isDispatching = function () {
    return this.$Dispatcher_isDispatching;
  };

  Dispatcher.prototype.$Dispatcher_invokeCallback = function (id) {
    this.$Dispatcher_isPending[id] = true;
    this.$Dispatcher_callbacks[id](this.$Dispatcher_pendingPayload);
    this.$Dispatcher_isHandled[id] = true;
  };

  Dispatcher.prototype.$Dispatcher_startDispatching = function (payload) {
    for (const id in this.$Dispatcher_callbacks) {
      this.$Dispatcher_isPending[id] = false;
      this.$Dispatcher_isHandled[id] = false;
    }
    this.$Dispatcher_pendingPayload = payload;
    this.$Dispatcher_isDispatching = true;
  };

  Dispatcher.prototype.$Dispatcher_stopDispatching = function () {
    this.$Dispatcher_pendingPayload = null;
    this.$Dispatcher_isDispatching = false;
  };

  return Dispatcher;
}
```

I'd much prefer to use a better alternative, or at least fix this issue if anyone could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

The default export looks like an (obsolete) wrapper function. You might need to "unwrap" it first:

```
import AppDispatcherWrapper from '../dispatcher/AppDispatcher';

const AppDispatcher = AppDispatcherWrapper();
AppDispatcher.register((payload) => {
  // ...
});
```